# Why does this data throw an error in R fitdistr?

Tags: r, fitting

I'm trying to fit a weibull distribution to this but am having problems. Not sure why. What causes the NaNs?

```
temp <- dput(temp)
c(477.25, 2615.56, 1279.98, 581.57, 13.55, 80.4, 6640.22, 759.46, 
1142.33, 134, 1232.23, 389.81, 7811.65, 992.11, 1152.4, 3139.01, 
2636.78, 3294.75, 2266.95, 32.12, 7356.84, 1448.54, 3606.82, 
465.39, 950.5, 3721.49, 522.01, 1548.62, 2196.3, 256.8, 2959.72, 
214.4, 134, 2307.79, 2112.74)


fitdist(temp, distr = "weibull", method = "mle")
Fitting of the distribution ' weibull ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
          estimate  Std. Error
shape    0.8949019   0.1205351
scale 1803.8816283 357.9042207
Warning messages:
1: In dweibull(c(477.25, 2615.56, 1279.98, 581.57, 13.55, 80.4, 6640.22,  :
  NaNs produced
2: In dweibull(c(477.25, 2615.56, 1279.98, 581.57, 13.55, 80.4, 6640.22,  :
  NaNs produced
3: In dweibull(c(477.25, 2615.56, 1279.98, 581.57, 13.55, 80.4, 6640.22,  :
  NaNs produced
4: In dweibull(c(477.25, 2615.56, 1279.98, 581.57, 13.55, 80.4, 6640.22,  :
  NaNs produced
5: In dweibull(c(477.25, 2615.56, 1279.98, 581.57, 13.55, 80.4, 6640.22,  :
  NaNs produced
6: In dweibull(c(477.25, 2615.56, 1279.98, 581.57, 13.55, 80.4, 6640.22,  :
  NaNs produced
7: In dweibull(c(477.25, 2615.56, 1279.98, 581.57, 13.55, 80.4, 6640.22,  :
  NaNs produced
8: In dweibull(c(477.25, 2615.56, 1279.98, 581.57, 13.55, 80.4, 6640.22,  :
  NaNs produced
9: In dweibull(c(477.25, 2615.56, 1279.98, 581.57, 13.55, 80.4, 6640.22,  :
  NaNs produced
10: In dweibull(c(477.25, 2615.56, 1279.98, 581.57, 13.55, 80.4, 6640.22,  :
  NaNs produced
```

Comment: Both parameters of the Weibull distribution are positive. If you type `fitdist(temp, distr = "weibull", method = "mle", lower = c(0, 0))` no errors will be produced. Otherwise, `optim` tries negatives values which in turn produce the error.

Comment: Thanks! Why was it trying parameters below as a default -- I would assume that the Weibull would only fit positive shape and scale parameters? Similarly, what should the "lower" be for gamma and how do you know? It's not documented in ?fitdist.

Comment: Although this is a question about understanding an R error message (ie presumably off topic programming Q), it seems the underlying issue might be understanding the nature of the Weibull distribution. Thus, it may be on topic here.

Comment: What package is the function `fitdist` coming from? I see `fitdistr` in `MASS`. CRAN can be quite lax with package evaluation.

Comment: @COOLSerdash, since that seems to resolve this, why not turn your comment into an official answer (& maybe expand it a bit)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Weibull_distribution) has two parameters, the scale $\lambda$ and shape $k$ (I'm following Wikipedia's notation). Both parameters are positive real numbers.

The function `fitdist` from the `fitdistrplus` package uses the `optim` function to find the maximum likelihood estimations of the parameters. By default, `optim` imposes no constraints on the parameters and tries out negative numbers as well. But negative values for the scale or shape produce `NaNs` for the Weibull distribution. By using the options `lower` and `upper`, you can impose limits on the parameter search space for `optim`.

The [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Gamma_distribution) also has two parameters and as with the Weibull distribution, both are positive. So the same limits `lower = c(0, 0)` can be used for the gamma distribution.

**Edit**

Here is a small comparison of the Weibull and gamma fit for the posted data. The errors for the gamma distribution arise because of bad starting values. I provide them manually and then it works fine without errors.

```
library(fitdistrplus)

temp <- c(477.25, 2615.56, 1279.98, 581.57, 13.55, 80.4, 6640.22, 759.46, 
          1142.33, 134, 1232.23, 389.81, 7811.65, 992.11, 1152.4, 3139.01, 
          2636.78, 3294.75, 2266.95, 32.12, 7356.84, 1448.54, 3606.82, 
          465.39, 950.5, 3721.49, 522.01, 1548.62, 2196.3, 256.8, 2959.72, 
          214.4, 134, 2307.79, 2112.74)

fit.weibull <- fitdist(temp, distr = "weibull", method = "mle", lower = c(0, 0))
fit.gamma <- fitdist(temp, distr = "gamma", method = "mle", lower = c(0, 0), start = list(scale = 1, shape = 1))
```

Plot the fit for the Weibull:

```
plot(fit.weibull)
```

[image: Weibull fit]

And for the gamma distribution:

```
plot(fit.gamma)
```

[image: Gamma fit]

They are practically indistinguishable. The AICs are virtually the same for both fits:

```
gofstat(list(fit.weibull, fit.gamma))

Goodness-of-fit statistics
                             1-mle-weibull 2-mle-gamma
Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic    0.07288424  0.07970184
Cramer-von Mises statistic      0.02532353  0.02361358
Anderson-Darling statistic      0.20489012  0.17609146

Goodness-of-fit criteria
                               1-mle-weibull 2-mle-gamma
Aikake's Information Criterion      601.7909    601.5659
Bayesian Information Criterion      604.9016    604.6766
```

Comment: lower = c(0,0) causes errors however...

Comment: @user1357015 When did the error occurr and what was it?

Comment: @COOLSerdah  `fitdist(temp, distr = "gamma", method = "mle", lower = c(0,0)) ` causes a `"Error in fitdist(splitData[[1]], distr = "gamma", method = "mle", lower = c(0,  : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
                with the error code 100 `

However, if I set `c(0,1)` it works fine though.

Comment: @user1357015 I have updated my answer accordingly. The error arises because of bad starting values.

Comment: Ok, so that works but now bootstrap also throws warnings, namely `bootdist(temp)'. I think some iterations fail to converge which mathematically seems fine since 993, out of 1001 iterations did converge -- but thought I'd double check :-)

Comment: @user1357015 Well, the `bootdist` requires a fitted distribution, not the raw data. But yes, it does produce the same errors as the fitting for the Weibull without the limits. Don't know how to fix that, I'm sorry.

Comment: That sounds like a LOUSY function for general purpose use. It is called with an argument specifying ti's a Webull, so appropriate constraints should be imposed automatically, in MY opinion. Yes, i could do that myself, but instead of going to the trouble to do that, I'd use a good nonlinear optimizer, not specialized to MLE, and likely much better than what fitdist uses, and I'd impose all appropriate constraints myself in my optimization problem formulation.

Comment: Bad starting values don't help matters, but fundamentally, fitdist appears not to be very good. if I was grading, I'd give it a gentleman's D.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I agree that the boundaries on the parameters should be hard-coded depending on the chosen distribution. Regarding bad starting values: I have never seen a decent implementation on that in *any* case, to be honest. Nonlinear least squares `nls` can be a nightmare in this respect. Personally, I think `fitdist` is not so bad: It uses `optim` which is a good general nonlinear optimizier (afaik). Also, it saves me the trouble of specifying the exact log-likelihood for each distribution making it easier for new users to fit the parameters. There is a lot of room for improvement!